# add KeyListener to JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing

Actually my registerKeyBoardAction with following code not working after I pressed Alt key for first time and again if I press Alt key it works means that Alt key is acting as a lock and unlock states i.e while in lock state keyBoard action doesnot work and in unlock state it works:

```
package com.remittance;

import Util.DayBookDetails;
import Util.MultiLineTableCellRenderer;
import Util.ReportPrint;
import UtilClass.DayBookDataList;
import com.fa.converter.DateUtil;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.io.File;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

/**
 *
 * @author Ashmin
 */
public class DayBook extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form DayBook
     */
private Session session;
private Connection connect;
private ResultSet result;
private PreparedStatement statement;
static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(DayBook.class.getName());
private String className = "com.remittance.DayBook";
private ActionListener showForm;
private final MultiLineTableCellRenderer renderer;

public DayBook(Session session) {

    initComponents();

    Action actionView = new AbstractAction("View") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        }
    };

    buttonView.setAction(actionView);

    actionView.putValue(Action.MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_V);

    buttonView.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), buttonView);

    buttonView.getActionMap().put(buttonView, actionView);

    this.panel.setVisible(false);

    showForm = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (panel.isVisible()) {
                panel.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                panel.setVisible(true);
            }

        }

    };
    this.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(showForm, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    this.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(showForm, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0), JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);

    ActionListener actionRefresh = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Refreshed");
            showDayBook();
        }
    };
    buttonRefresh.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(actionRefresh, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F5, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    buttonRefresh.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(actionRefresh, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F5, 0), JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tableDayBook = new javax.swing.JTable();
    labelDateAd = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    inputTextFieldDateBsFrom = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    inputTextFieldDateBsTo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    checkBoxRemark = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    buttonView = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane4 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tableShortcut = new javax.swing.JTable();
    buttonRefresh = new javax.swing.JButton();
    panelTitle = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelPan = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelLogo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelContact = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelCompanyName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelLocation = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelDayBook = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelDate = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setClosable(true);
    setIconifiable(true);
    setMaximizable(true);
    setTitle("Day Book");
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1180, 560));

    tableDayBook.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "Date", "Particular", "Vouchar Type", "VNo", "Dr. Amount", "Cr. Amount"
        }
    ) {
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false, false, false, false
        };

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    tableDayBook.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    tableDayBook.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            tableDayBookKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tableDayBook);
    if (tableDayBook.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
        tableDayBook.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
        tableDayBook.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
        tableDayBook.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
        tableDayBook.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
        tableDayBook.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setResizable(false);
        tableDayBook.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setResizable(false);
    }

    labelDateAd.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    labelDateAd.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    jLabel1.setText("*");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Date (YYYY-MM-DD) In BS:   From:");

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("To:");

    inputTextFieldDateBsFrom.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            inputTextFieldDateBsFromFocusLost(evt);
        }
    });
    inputTextFieldDateBsFrom.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            inputTextFieldDateBsFromKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });

    inputTextFieldDateBsTo.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            inputTextFieldDateBsToFocusLost(evt);
        }
    });
    inputTextFieldDateBsTo.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            inputTextFieldDateBsToKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });

    checkBoxRemark.setText("Remark");
    checkBoxRemark.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            checkBoxRemarkKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });

    buttonView.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    buttonView.setText("View");
    buttonView.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            buttonViewFocusGained(evt);
        }
    });
    buttonView.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            buttonViewActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    buttonView.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            buttonViewKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
    panel.setLayout(panelLayout);
    panelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(inputTextFieldDateBsFrom, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 175, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(inputTextFieldDateBsTo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 212, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(checkBoxRemark)
            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
            .addComponent(buttonView)
            .addContainerGap(330, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    panelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(3, 3, 3)
            .addGroup(panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(inputTextFieldDateBsFrom, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(inputTextFieldDateBsTo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(checkBoxRemark)
                .addComponent(buttonView))
            .addGap(0, 2, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    tableShortcut.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "Shortcut Keys"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jScrollPane4.setViewportView(tableShortcut);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane4)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    buttonRefresh.setText("Refresh");
    buttonRefresh.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            buttonRefreshActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    buttonRefresh.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            buttonRefreshKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel5.setText("Pan No:");

    labelPan.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    labelPan.setText("Pan");

    labelLogo.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    labelLogo.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel4.setText("Contact:");

    labelContact.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    labelContact.setText("PHone");

    labelCompanyName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    labelCompanyName.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelCompanyName.setText("Company Name");

    labelLocation.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    labelLocation.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelLocation.setText("Location");

    labelDayBook.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    labelDayBook.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelDayBook.setText("Day Book");

    labelDate.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    labelDate.setText("Date in AD: ");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelTitleLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panelTitle);
    panelTitle.setLayout(panelTitleLayout);
    panelTitleLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelTitleLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelTitleLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, 0)
            .addGroup(panelTitleLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(panelTitleLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                    .addComponent(labelPan))
                .addComponent(labelLogo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(panelTitleLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(panelTitleLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(panelTitleLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(labelCompanyName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(panelTitleLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                            .addComponent(labelContact))
                        .addComponent(labelLocation, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(labelDayBook, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, panelTitleLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(labelDate)
                    .addGap(19, 19, 19))))
    );
    panelTitleLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelTitleLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(panelTitleLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(panelTitleLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addComponent(labelPan)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(labelContact))
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addGroup(panelTitleLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(panelTitleLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(labelCompanyName)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(labelLocation)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(labelDayBook)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(labelDate))
                .addComponent(labelLogo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jButton1.setText("Print");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(panelTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(buttonRefresh)))
            .addGap(0, 0, 0)
            .addComponent(labelDateAd))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(123, 123, 123)
                    .addComponent(labelDateAd))
                .addComponent(panelTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(0, 0, 0)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 312, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(0, 0, 0)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(buttonRefresh)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        



private void buttonViewActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    panel.setVisible(false);
}                                          

private void inputTextFieldDateBsFromKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                                    
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        inputTextFieldDateBsTo.requestFocus();
    }
}                                                   

private void inputTextFieldDateBsToKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                                  
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        buttonView.requestFocus();
    }
}                                                 

private void checkBoxRemarkKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                          
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        checkBoxRemark.setSelected(true);
    }
}                                         

private void tableDayBookKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F2) {
        //panel.setVisible(true);
        showForm.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, null) {
            //Nothing need go here, the actionPerformed method (with the
            //above arguments) will trigger the respective listener
        });

    }
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ALT) {
        evt.consume();
    }
}                                       

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton buttonRefresh;
private javax.swing.JButton buttonView;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox checkBoxRemark;
private javax.swing.JTextField inputTextFieldDateBsFrom;
private javax.swing.JTextField inputTextFieldDateBsTo;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane4;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelCompanyName;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelContact;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelDate;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelDateAd;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelDayBook;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelLocation;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelLogo;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelPan;
private javax.swing.JPanel panel;
private javax.swing.JPanel panelTitle;
private javax.swing.JTable tableDayBook;
private javax.swing.JTable tableShortcut;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

I have searched and found that if I consume the event on Alt key pressed then I will have problem fixed but I am unable to addKeyListener to JInternalFrame. Please! Help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on my testing, it works fine

Comment: But in my case it's not working ....can you please help to add key listener???

Comment: Provide me with a runnable example which doesn't work

Comment: @MadProgrammer Please check the edited post

Comment: @MadProgrammer Actually it is not working when I used F2 as a shortcut key when I used 'O' it's working fine

Comment: F2 is an OS specific shortcut (from memory, it brings up the window menu), you can't override it

Comment: That means we have to use other key???

Comment: Pretty much...,

Comment: anyway thanks a lot